# Python Automatization

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement

the following problem may be a bit confusing but I will try to explain it in the best possible way.

Let's assume that we work for a manufacturing company. Which manufactures components that are then used to make products. In the following example there are 3 components and 2 final products.

The demands of components and products are the following:

```
comp1 = 8
comp2 = 3
comp3 = 5
prod1 = 2
prod2 = 2
```

Which can be saved in a dictionary:

```
clst = {"comp": [comp1, comp2, comp3], "prod": [prod1, prod2]}
```

On the other hand, to manufacture a final product, the components requirements are the following:

prod1 need: 2 comp1, 1 comp2, 1 comp3

prod2 need: 3 comp1, 1 comp2, 2 comp3

In a dictionary:

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2]}
```

I need to create a list that contains a list of contributions and consumptions of material that mixes the data in the following way:

```
[
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2],            # ---->comp1/prod1(1)
                 [1, 1, 1, -1],               # ---->comp2/prod1(1)
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]         # ---->comp3/prod1(1)
    ]
    ,
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2],            # ---->comp1/prod1(2)
                 [1, 1, 1, -1],               # ---->comp2/prod1(2)
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]         # ---->comp3/prod1(2)
    ]
    ,
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3],            # ---->comp1/prod2(1)
                 [1, 1, 1, -1],               # ---->comp2/prod2(1)
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]         # ---->comp3/prod3(1)
    ]
    ,
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3],            # ---->comp1/prod2(2)
                 [1, 1, 1, -1],               # ---->comp2/prod2(2)
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]         # ---->comp3/prod3(2)
    ]
]
```

The quantity of 1 in a list corresponds to the quantity of the demand of the component, the final number in negative is the requirement of components of the product.

Any suggestions to make the list?

Comment: What determines the number of 1s in a list, such as the list `# ---->comp1/prod1(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a readable format of the code:

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2]}
clst = {"comp": [8, 3, 5], "prod": [2, 2]}

lst = []

for i, prod_demand in enumerate(clst["prod"]):
    sub_list = []
    for j, comp_demand in enumerate(clst["comp"]):
        sub_list.append([1]*comp_demand+[rprod[i][j]*(-1)])
    for k in range(prod_demand):
        lst.append(sub_list)
```

But if you want to condense it, you can just write:

```
rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2]}
clst = {"comp": [8, 3, 5], "prod": [2, 2]}

lst = []

for i, p in enumerate(clst["prod"]):
    lst += [[[1]*c+[rprod[i][j]*(-1)] for j, c in enumerate(clst["comp"])]]*p
```

Comment: @jpss I answered first though?

Comment: By like 10 seconds, I'd call that a tie @DeliriousLettuce ;)

Comment: @Jonas My answer is much clearer though, this code runs right off the page.

Comment: Fixed as in used shorter variable names so that it no longer runs off the page. I included 1 readable version and one (arguably more pythonic) shorter version, which isn't meant to be readable but concise. @DeliriousLettuce

Comment: @Jonas Isn't meant to be readable? [`"Readability counts"`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172924/discussion-between-jonas-and-delirious-lettuce).

Answer (score 2):

```
In[2]: comp1 = 8
  ...: comp2 = 3
  ...: comp3 = 5
  ...: prod1 = 2
  ...: prod2 = 2
  ...: 
  ...: clst = {"comp": [comp1, comp2, comp3], "prod": [prod1, prod2]}
  ...: rprod = {0: [2,1,1], 1: [3,1,2]}
In[3]: result = []
  ...: for i, p in enumerate(clst['prod']):
  ...:     for _ in range(p):
  ...:         tmp = [([1] * a) + [-b] for a, b in zip(clst['comp'], rprod[i])]
  ...:         result.append(tmp)
  ...: 
In[4]: result
Out[4]: 
[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3], [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2]]]
```